# javascript date validation is not working for today date

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date, datetime

I have got below java script code that will validates date range ... when the user entered the today date or any future dates I have set IsValid to true and then will do the save operation ....

for that purpose I have written below code ..

```
 function Save(e) {
    var popupNotification = $("#popupNotification").data("kendoNotification");

    var container = e.container;
    var model = e.model;

    var isValid = true;
    var compareDate = e.model.DeliveryDate;
    alert(compareDate);
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var compareDateModified = new Date(compareDate)
    alert(compareDateModified);
    if (compareDateModified > todayDate || compareDateModified === todayDate) {
        isValid = true;

    }
    else
        isValid = false;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isValid == false)
    {

        popupNotification.show("Delivery Date should be today date or Greater", "error");

    }
    $('#Previous').show();
    $('#Next').show();
}
```

Its working fine when I give the future dates but its not working for today date. I also need to check the today's date. I am not able to figure it out the error alert when I try to enter to the today date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the Date object like a timestamp. It is based on the unix-style of timestamps (the amount of seconds since 1st January, 1970) so the Date object isn't the day, it is the Date AND the Time.

What you're comparing is the times as well, which could get a little iffy. If only days matter, try using:

```
fullCompareDate = compareDateModified.getFullYear() + "/" + compareDateModified.getMonth() + "/" + compareDateModified.getDate();
fullTodayDate= todayDate.getFullYear() + "/" + todayDate.getMonth() + "/" + todayDate.getDate();
if(compareDateModified>todayDate||fullCompareDate==fullTodayDate)
{
  //Do something
}
```

This will compare the date and time to make sure they are greater OR check the current date with the compare date (as strings)

Another solution is to blank out the times on both dates:

```
compareDateModified.setHours(0,0,0,0);
todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
if(compareDateModified>=todayDate)
{
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two objects of the same type, but different objects, so that will always result in 'unequal'
If you use date.getTime() you will get better results in your comparison - but only if the time component is the same of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the compareDateModified to todayDate on the millisecond level.  To compare at the day level:

```
var todayDate = new Date();
todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
//you may also have to truncate the compareDateModified to the first
//second of the day depending on how you setup compareDate
if (compareDateModified >= todayDate) {
    isValid = true;
}
```